# Clicking on the Image presented with Captcha opens another Captcha

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha

At least seen on the [tex](http://tex.stackexchange.com) board (I haven't had a captcha on any other forum since I noticed this). The funny image presented with the captcha request is hyperlinked to another captcha with the same exact seed, i.e. it opens up another tab with asking for another captcha. As seen in this screen capture. The 4 "human verification" tabs were opened by simply clicking on the image. Compare the link target (shown at the bottom of the browser window) with the URL of the captcha.

[image]

I haven't clicked submit on more than one yet. Don't want to break my post edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch -- if the CAPTCHA image link is not set, we should not be rendering the hyperlink markup for it because it turns into.

```
<a href=""><img src="http://example.com/foo.png"></a>
```

This fix will be deployed tomorrow.